# Declare a read-only @NSManaged property in Swift for Parse's PFRelation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform, pfrelation

I'm using [Parse object store](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-properties-amp-methods) in my iOS application and I've created a custom subclass for my Parse object, which looks somewhat like this:

```
class MyThing: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

   // ...PFSubclassing protocol...

   @NSManaged var name: String
   @NSManaged var somethingElse: String
   @NSManaged var relatedThings: PFRelation

 }
```

The `relatedThings` property works: I am able to fetch the related objects from the store. However, I keep getting this warning from Parse:

```
[Warning]: PFRelation properties are always readonly,
but MyApp.MyThing.relatedThings was declared otherwise.
```

In Objective-C, I could have easily marked that property as readonly, but I am unsure how to do that in Swift to silence the warning.

Using `let` instead of `var` is not allowed in combination with `@NSManaged`.

Adding `private(set)` has no effect either:

```
@NSManaged private(set) var relatedThings: PFRelation
```

So how does Parse expect me to declare the relationship property?

Comment: I don't have this warning

Comment: There is a chance this is a Swift 2.0 specific issue, but I cannot confirm that right now. Will update the question once I do.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't have this warning in my parse project in Xcode7 beta 5 with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you should use:

```
var relatedThings: PFRelation! {
    return relationForKey("relatedThings")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32128580/482493) did not work for me, as `PFObject` is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, thus it doesn't implement the `willAccessValueForKey`, `primitiveValueForKey`, and `didAccessValueForKey` methods.

However, using `PFObject`'s own `objectForKey` method is the correct equivalent solution:

```
var relatedThings: PFRelation! {
    return objectForKey("relatedThings") as? PFRelation
}
```

You still need to either force-cast the value that method returns to `PFRelation`, or, as per Tom's version, turn the property's type into an optional.

Comment: See iGenio's answer for correct answer, this answer caused an error when trying to do anything with the PFRelation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd make a read-only Core Data property with Swift. I don't know if this is what Parse is looking for, but it's how things would work in Swift.

Although Xcode generates `NSManagedObject` subclasses with `@NSManaged` on the attributes, it's not actually required. It's fine to replace `@NSManaged` attributes with equivalent Swift computed properties that use Core Data primitive accessors to get/set property values. You'd make the property *effectively* readonly by not including a setter.

That would mean replacing your existing `relatedThings` declaration with something like this:

```
var relatedThings : PFRelation? {
    get {
        self.willAccessValueForKey("relatedThings")
        let things = self.primitiveValueForKey("relatedThings") as? PFRelation
        self.didAccessValueForKey("relatedThings")

        return things
    }
}
```

This `get` code will work the same as it would if you were using `@NSManaged`. But by not having a `set`, the property is read-only.

Comment: I realize that you can define a computed var with only a get. My question was regarding defining a var as get only without adding all this, seemingly unessesarry code.

Comment: Not if you're using Swift and Core Data.